# Unable to get current user data between two dates in Django

Tags: django

```
current_user = request.user
if LeadTarget.objects.filter(user_id__username=current_user):
    start_date = LeadTarget.objects.filter(user_id__username=current_user).values('start_date','deadline')
    startdate = []
    deadline = []
    for i in start_date:
        startdate.append(i['start_date'])
        deadline.append(i['deadline'])
    print("-------")
    print(startdate)
    start = (startdate[0])
    print("start",start)
    print(type(start))
    print(deadline)
    user_data = LeadTarget.objects.filter(created_at__range=(startdate, deadline))
    print("data =======: ", user_data)
    if user_data:
        for i in user_data:
            print("data : ", i)
    else:
        print("empty")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime

# for example the start date 
start_date = '18-05-2020'

# for example the deadline
deadline = '20-05-2020'

start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d-%m-%Y")

deadline = datetime.datetime.strptime(deadline, "%d-%m-%Y")

# query for the data between two dates
LeadTarget.objects.filter(created_at__gte=start_date,created_at__lte=deadline)



# Changes in your function can be like this

user_data_list = []
current_user = request.user
# current_user is a user object
if LeadTarget.objects.filter(user=current_user):
    leadtargetdata = LeadTarget.objects.filter(user=current_user).values('start_date','deadline')

    # so you will get the data like this
    # [{'start_date': datetime.date(2020, 12, 10), 'deadline': datetime.date(2020, 12, 18)}, {...}]

    for leadtarget in leadtargetdata:
        start_date = leadtarget['start_date']
        deadline = leadtarget['deadline']
        user_data = LeadTarget.objects.filter(created_at__gte=,created_at__lte=deadline)

        print(user_data)

        # if you want to add data to list
        user_data_list.append(user_data)

    print("User data is {}".format(user_data))
```

Comment: Here you are giving Static Date but what about when data is coming from Database ?? that time date is in the list format and looks like this datetime.date(2020, 12, 18) is output from DB But we need date like this 2020-12-18

Comment: you can format your date like this:- datetime.datetime.strftime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")

Answer (score 0):

I think you couldn't filter the `username` field by `<User: ..>` object. Try to change:

```
LeadTarget.objects.filter(user_id__username=current_user)
```

into;

```
LeadTarget.objects.filter(user_id=current_user)
```

> Also in your case the output of `startdate` and `deadline` list of dates, you should change it into `date` or `datetime` format. [Read more about `__range` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range).

Comment: TypeError : expected string or bytes-like object                                                            . user_data =LeadTarget.objects.filter(start_date__range=(startdate, today_date))

Comment: of course, in your case the output of `startdate` list of dates, you should change it into `date` or `datetime` format.